# ArrayList Adapter only updates View after manualy adding objects

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-view

Sorry the title is pretty bad,

Basically I have an adapter `aa = new tweetAdapter(this, resID, tweetListFull);` which only updates after I use `aa.add` and then `aa.notifyDataSetChanged()` my understanding is that this should work with `tweetListFull.add` and then `aa.notifyDataSetChanged()` aswell...

So when I use `aa.add(tweetListFull.get(0))` and `aa.notifyDataSetChanged()` the view is added as expected. Although From what I thought I thought that adding items to the tweetListFull list sand then `aa.notifyDataSetChanged()` should also work but it doesn't?

### MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    render = new tweetView(this);

    LinearLayout canvas = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    ListView tweetList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.tweetView);

    tweetListFull = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
    int resID = R.layout.tweet;
    aa = new tweetAdapter(this, resID, tweetListFull);

    Log.w("Check","Here1");        
    tweetList.setAdapter(aa);
    Log.w("Check","Here1");
    //tweetList.addView()
    canvas.addView(render);



    // UI //        
    drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items); 
    // get ListView defined in activity_main.xml
    drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer); 
    // Set the adapter for the list view
    drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));



    Button.OnClickListener listener = new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v.getId() == R.id.Refresh){                  
                twitterTest tweet = new twitterTest();
                tweet.execute(-3.19523741,56.21523879); // The argument for this is the query to search for.
            }
            else if(v.getId() == R.id.Load){
                Log.w("Load1",String.valueOf(tweetListFull));
                Log.w("Load1",String.valueOf(tweetListFull.size()));
                //aa.add(tweetListFull.get(2));
                aa.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }               
        }
    };
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.Refresh)).setOnClickListener(listener);  
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.Load)).setOnClickListener(listener);  
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

### tweetAdapter

```
package com.example.networkingcoursework;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class tweetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tweet>{

int resource;

public tweetAdapter(Context _context, int _resource,ArrayList<Tweet> _objects) {
    super(_context, _resource, _objects);
    resource = _resource;
    Log.w("Test222","Test3:"+String.valueOf(_resource));
    Log.w("Test222","Test3:"+String.valueOf(_objects.size()));

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    Log.w("Test222","Test22!");
    LinearLayout tweetView;
    Tweet tweet = getItem(position);
    Log.w("Test222","Test!");

    long tweetId = tweet.getId();

    if(convertView == null){
        tweetView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
        vi.inflate(resource,tweetView, true);
    }
    else{
        tweetView = (LinearLayout) convertView;     
    }

    TextView idView = (TextView)tweetView.findViewById(R.id.tweetText);
    idView.setText(String.valueOf(tweetId));
    Log.w("Test222","Test!");
    return tweetView;

}
```

}

Comment: ArrayAdapter requires you to work directly with it, via add, addAll, clear, remove and not the array itself.. if you need to work with the array itself and not the Adapter you will need to use BaseAdapter instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

notifyDataSetChanged only works when you add one or more items to tweetListFull; you can do something like this:

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.Load)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 tweetListFull.add(yourNewItem);
                 aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

}